# Serializing SQLAlchemy with Marshmallow

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm following a tutorial and using the below code. I'm also using Postman to view the status of the server for http://localhost:5000/planets , but I'm getting **500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR,** when I should see my JSON data of the planets I created.
In the command line I also see: **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'**

I feel it might have to do with the line that has: return jsonify(result.data) but I'm not sure.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float
import os
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from marshmallow import Schema

app = Flask(__name__)

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:/Users/krist/Py3/flask2/planets.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

@app.cli.command('db_create')
def db_create():
    db.create_all()
    print("DB Created")

@app.cli.command('db_seed')
def deb_seed():
    mercury = Planet(planet_name='Mercury',
                     planet_type='Class D',
                     home_star='Sol',
                     mass=3.25e23,
                     radius=1516,
                     distance=35.98e6)

    venus = Planet(planet_name='Venus',
                     planet_type='Class K',
                     home_star='Sol',
                     mass=8.95e24,
                     radius=3516,
                     distance=67.98e6)

    earth = Planet(planet_name='Earth',
                     planet_type='Class M',
                     home_star='Sol',
                     mass=5.97e24,
                     radius=3916,
                     distance=92.96e6)

    db.session.add(mercury)
    db.session.add(venus)
    db.session.add(earth)

    test_user = User(first_name='William',
                     last_name='Hershel',
                     email='test@test.com',
                     password='p@ssw0rd')

    db.session.add(test_user)
    db.session.commit()
    print("DB Seeded")

@app.route('/planets', methods=['GET'])
def planets():
    planets_list = Planet.query.all()
    result = planets_schema.dump(planets_list)
    return jsonify(result.data)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    password = Column(String)

class Planet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'planets'
    planet_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    planet_name = Column(String)
    planet_type = Column(String)
    home_star = Column(String)
    mass = Column(Float)
    radius = Column(Float)
    distance = Column(Float)


class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

class PlanetSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('planet_id', 'planet_name', 'planet_type', 'home_star', 'mass', 'radius', 'distance')

user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

planet_schema = PlanetSchema()
planets_schema = PlanetSchema(many=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I think perhaps you need to define the data variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
result = planets_schema.dump(planets_list)
return jsonify(result.data)
```

Try

```
result = planets_schema.dump(planets_list)
return jsonify(result)
```

Why this works:

Here you are querying the Planet Mapper to return a list of Planet ORM objects

```
planets_list = Planet.query.all()
```

Then the Marshmallow schema is used to marshal, or transform the ORM object into a python dictionary object. This is the basic principle of marshaling - transforming data from one format into another when the data is about to be transmitted or stored. So in this case you transform you data from a list of SQLAlchemy ORM objects into a list of Python dictionary objects.

```
result = planets_schema.dump(planets_list)
```

Now you have `result` (which could more aptly be names `results` that contains a list of dictionary objects.
Then you are attempting to access the `data` variable on this list object. However Python lists have no `data` variable, so you get an error.

```
return jsonify(result.data)
```

The `jsonify` method from flask accepts a list of dictionaries as input, so simply modifying this line to the below should work:

```
return jsonify(result)
```